Finding determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix.
Let $A_{n\times n}$=$((a_{ij}))$ $n\geq {3}$, where $a_{ij}=(b_i^2-b_j^2)$, $i,j=1,2,\ldots ,n$ for some distinct real numbers $b_1,b_2,\ldots ,b_n$.
Then what is $\det(A)$?
Clearly the matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric and if $n$ is odd then the determinant is zero.
I want to prove that for any $n\ge4$, $\det(A)$ is $0$.
For the case when $n=4$, I have calculated the determinant by ordinary method.
I want to generalize it, please someone help.
Thank you.

Hint: write $A$ as the difference of two rank-$1$ matrices; what does that tell you about the rank and determinant of $A$? (Small detail: the determinant isn't necessariiy $0$ when $n=2$.)

Thank you for your correction.I have edited my post,but I am unable to write A as the difference of rank-1 matrices .Please explain.thank you.

As Greg mentioned: $[b_i^2-b_j^2]{(i,j)} = [b_i^2]{(i,j)}-[b_j^2]_{(i,j)}$.

Just write them out for say $n=3$ and you will "see" it :-)

@Math-fun got it.

By the way of your example with $n=4$, for $b_i=i; 1\le i\le6$, we have un example giving determinant null with $n\gt4$ and even.

Let the determinant of the matrix of order $n\gt3$ with the above conditions
$$\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}0&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\cdots& a_{1n}\\a_{21}&0&a_{23}&a_{24}\cdots&a_{2n}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&0 &a_{34}\cdots&a_{3n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&a_{n3}&\cdots&0\end{vmatrix}\end{equation}$$
Note that $\boxed{a_{ij}-a_{ik}=a_{kj}}$.
Subtracting the second column from the first we get $$\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}-a_{12}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\cdots& a_{1n}\\a_{21}&0&a_{23}&a_{24}\cdots&a_{2n}\\a_{21}&a_{32}&0 &a_{34}\cdots&a_{3n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{21}&a_{n2}&a_{n3}&\cdots&0\end{vmatrix}\end{equation}$$
and subtracting now the third column from the second we get $$\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}-a_{12}&a_{32}&a_{13}&a_{14}\cdots& a_{1n}\\a_{21}&-a_{23}&a_{23}&a_{24}\cdots&a_{2n}\\a_{21}&a_{32}&0 &a_{34}\cdots&a_{3n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{21}&a_{32}&a_{n3}&\cdots&0\end{vmatrix}\end{equation}$$ Since $-a_{12}=a_{21}$ and $-a_{23}=a_{32}$ we have $$\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}a_{21}&a_{32}&a_{13}&a_{14}\cdots& a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{32}&a_{23}&a_{24}\cdots&a_{2n}\\a_{21}&a_{32}&0 &a_{34}\cdots&a_{3n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{21}&a_{32}&a_{n3}&\cdots&0\end{vmatrix}\end{equation}$$
which yields $$a_{21}a_{32}\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&a_{13}&a_{14}\cdots& a_{1n}\\1&1&a_{23}&a_{24}\cdots&a_{2n}\\1&1&0 &a_{34}\cdots&a_{3n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1&1&a_{n3}&\cdots&0\end{vmatrix}\end{equation}=0$$
